# Using Bing Location API with 3rd party map

Tags: openlayers-3, bing-maps

I'm trying to determine if it is allowed to use [Bing Map's Location API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701715.aspx) and display and use the results in conjunction with a 3rd party map, such as OpenLayers.

I've dug through their [license agreement](https://www.microsoft.com/maps/product/terms.html) and can't find clear direction one way or another.

The primary portion dealing with this seems to be section 3.2. General Restrictions.

> **(d)** Use Content, including geocodes, other than via an authenticated call to the Services and/or in conjunction with a Bing Map.
>
> **(i)** Use Content other than in combination with the Services and not separately.

I've focused on these two restrictions in particular. (d) implies to me that it is possible to use without Bing Map, as long as the Content is being access through the appropriate, authenticated Service.  However, does (i) exclude independent use?

---

Google is much more plain text about this:

> If your application displays Google Places API Web Service data on a map, that map must be provided by Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any of the Bing Maps services with 3rd party map controls provide they use the Bing Maps map tiles. OpenLayers, Leaflet, and many other 3rd party map controls provide a way to use Bing Maps tiles already. Here is an example of using the Bing Maps tiles in OpenLayers: http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/bing-maps.html

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Evaluating what the possible options and combinations are. If we need to use Bing tiles, we will likely use V8.